# MySQL Join a table to itself

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get a MySQL report but getting nothing. Please point out what is wrong? I checked this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005643/mysql-left-join-one-table-to-itself) but cant find solution to my problem.

## TABLE VALUES

```
+----+-----+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| pk | ind | opt_type | name    | opt_type1 | opt_type2 |
+----+-----+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| 1  | 1   | group_1  | Green   | -         | -         |
| 2  | 1   | group_1  | Red     | -         | -         |
| 3  | 1   | group_2  | Cloth   | -         | -         |
| 4  | 1   | group_3  | Shirt   | 1         | 3         |
| 5  | 1   | group_4  | Table   | 2         | -         |
+----+-----+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

## REQUIRED OUTPUT

```
name  | colour | material
------+--------+---------
Shirt | Green  | Cloth
Table | Red    |
```

## QUERY & CODE

```
    SELECT
    o.name         
    , o1.name as colour
    , o2.name as material

    FROM $options as o
    LEFT JOIN $options AS o1 ON o1.opt_type1 = o.pk
    LEFT JOIN $options AS o2 ON o2.opt_type2 = o.pk                    

    WHERE o.ind=$ind
    AND o1.ind=$ind
    AND o2.ind=$ind


    LOOP{
    echo $name ." ". $colour ." ". $material;
    }
```

Comment: Could You please show final query with `$options` and `$ind` replaced with actual values?

Comment: what is in  $options

Comment: Have a look at using `GROUP_CONCAT` [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: show your expected result

Comment: @JYoThl its already mentioned under: REQUIRED OUTPUT

Comment: It would have been better had you copied and pasted the table data instead of using an image. Some people here are blocked from images and cannot read your question accordingly. Please change this. (I've formatted your output, so you see how it works :-)

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner This image is taken from my failed try to paste text table. I spent 20 minutes formatting the table & then finally took the image. :)

Comment: Too bad. In the image it looks like plain text you could just copy and paste and surround it with `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner  Thanks, next time I will remember your tip.

Comment: Look, it took my only some minutes to type it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That data model looks horrible to me. But anyway, if you want to outer-join a table, don't put criteria on it in the `WHERE` clause. An outer-joined record has all values set to null, so `o2.ind=$ind` can never be true for such a record. You end up with an inner join, thus dismissing the complete row. Put your join criteria into the `ON` clauses instead.

You also confused the IDs in the joins. `o` is your main option (e.g. 'Shirt') and `o1` is its first option (i.e. colour, e.g. 'Green'), so it must be `o1.pk = o.opt_type1`, not `o1.opt_type1 = o.pk`.

```
SELECT
  o.name         
, o1.name as colour
, o2.name as material
FROM $options as o
LEFT JOIN $options AS o1 ON o1.pk = o.opt_type1 AND o1.ind = o.ind
LEFT JOIN $options AS o2 ON o2.pk = o.opt_type2 AND o2.ind = o.ind 
WHERE o.ind = $ind AND (o.opt_type1 is not null or o.opt_type2 is not null);
```

Comment: Actual problem is very abstract & here I have tried to reproduce the problem. Let me try your solution.